# Hide/show pages depending on landing page click

Tags: 7

Last year i created a drupal 7 website for a MMA Trainer . He's pretty happy about it.
But now he wants to expand his business to personal training and has some new requirements.

He wants a landing page where people can click on 1 of 2 links(Gym / Personal training)
Depending on what the user clicks i have to hide/show certain pages on the website

How would i go about doing this ? Is there somekind of variable i can set on a landing page that i can check in drupal to hide pages ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module with [Subfolders Domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/subfolders_domain) to create two instances Gym and personal training. This will allow you to administer content for both sections.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of modules exists for your requirement. Have a look at the following modules.

[Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs)

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content, specifically views, blocks, nodes and other quicktabs. You can create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with corresponding content. Clicking on the tabs makes the corresponding content display instantly, using jQuery. With the 6.x-2.x branch, this can be done in either ajax or non-ajax mode:

[Ajaxify Drupal with JQuery Ajax](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api)

> Ajax links API module help you to load any content to a specified DIV or ajaxify whole drupal site, using JQuery Ajax. This module will also load JS for Ajax-loaded content by using Drupal.attachBehaviors(). In case you dont want to load js or css, you can alter tpl for path/node type.

[jQuery AJAX Load](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ajax_load)

> jQuery AJAX Load is an helper module for easy loading any content using build in jQuery load function.
>
> It comes with a set of modules that uses the functionality for:
>
> - Loading content on a link
> - Loading content on a Twitter Bootstrap Modal